# Chromatic adaptation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to make these gray images to color images so i can observe the chromatic adaptation

Another other things is how to apply Bradford transformation to the images (so to multiply the image with the Bradford Matrix

```
 Mbfd = [.8950 .2664 -.1614;
       -.7502 1.7135 .0367;
       .0389 -.0685 1.0296])
```

I know that I have to multiply the input image with the Bradford matrix but I don't know how to do it exactly.

```
I=imread('snimka.jpeg');
figure(1), imshow(I);
srgb2lab_byA = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint',whitepoint('a')); 
srgb2lab_byD50 = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint',whitepoint('d50'));
srgb2lab_byD55 = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint',whitepoint('d55'));
srgb2lab_byD65 = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint',whitepoint('d65'));
lab_A = applycform(I,srgb2lab_byA); 
lab_D50 = applycform(I,srgb2lab_byD50); 
lab_D55 = applycform(I,srgb2lab_byD55); 
lab_D65 = applycform(I,srgb2lab_byD65); 

% figure;
figure();
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(lab_A(:,:,1)); title('sRGB to Lab by adapting to illuminant A'); 
subplot(2,2,2), imhist(lab_A(:,:,1)); title('Histogram of the red channel');
subplot(2,2,3), imhist(lab_A(:,:,2)); title('Histogram of the green channel');
subplot(2,2,4), imhist(lab_A(:,:,3)); title('Histogram of the blue channel');
figure();
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(lab_D50(:,:,1)); title('sRGB to Lab by adapting to illuminant D50');
subplot(2,2,2), imhist(lab_D50(:,:,1)); title('Histogram of the red channel');
subplot(2,2,3), imhist(lab_D50(:,:,2)); title('Histogram of the green channel');
subplot(2,2,4), imhist(lab_D50(:,:,3)); title('Histogram of the blue channel');
% luminance_diff=abs(lab_A(:,:,1)-lab_D50(:,:,1));
figure();
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(lab_D55(:,:,1)); title('sRGB to Lab by adapting to illuminant D55');
subplot(2,2,2), imhist(lab_D55(:,:,1)); title('Histogram of the red channel');
subplot(2,2,3), imhist(lab_D55(:,:,2)); title('Histogram of the green channel');
subplot(2,2,4), imhist(lab_D55(:,:,3)); title('Histogram of the blue channel');
figure();
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(lab_D65(:,:,1)); title('sRGB to Lab by adapting to illuminant D65');
subplot(2,2,2), imhist(lab_D65(:,:,1)); title('Histogram of the red channel');
subplot(2,2,3), imhist(lab_D65(:,:,2)); title('Histogram of the green channel');
subplot(2,2,4), imhist(lab_D65(:,:,3)); title('Histogram of the blue channel');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not make color images from gray images. A gray image has less information there is no way of obtaining the color from gray images. However, your images appear to be clearly RGB. The reason the code you show shows grayscale, is because you are only showing one channel  (R, G , B) of the image. `imshow(I)` will show you the image.

To show the resulting ones from your operations, you need to convert them to rgb again. Assuming you want to see the whitelevel changed:

```
torgb= makecform('lab2srgb'); 
Irgb=applycform(lab_D55,torgb);
imshow(Irgb);
```

To apply the matrix you mention to an image, filter it:

```
Mbfd = [.8950 .2664 -.1614; -.7502 1.7135 .0367; .0389 -.0685 1.0296]);
out=imfilter(I, Mbfd);
```

---

Overal your question hints lack of understanding. I suggest you read what RGB and Lab are and what the white level does. Read too what a gray level image is vs a color image. This will greatly help you in the future.